# Tidy combine columns or rows simultaneously apply formats

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Context: I'm working on building some functions that automate table generation and styling for report generation (i.e., late-stage analytic work). The approach I'm taking is to wrangle my data into data frames that I will feed to 'flextable' for further processing. At various points in the workflow, I need to collapse rows or columns and apply some formatting.

In the example code below you will find two data frames, long_df and wide_df, I'd like to get these to look like respective target data frames. I'm stuck on the approach.

I thought maybe 'tidyr::unite' or using paste in 'dplyr::mutate' when in long form. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
library(tibble)

long_df <- tribble(
  ~Statistc, ~Model_1, ~Model_2,
  'G2',       413.42,  532.93,
  'df',       2,       3,
  'CFI',      .95,     .91,
)


wide_df <- tribble(
  ~model,     ~G2,     ~df,  ~CFI,
  'Model_1',  413.42,  2,   .95, 
  'Model_2',  532.93,  3,   .91, 
)


target_wide_df <- tribble(
  ~model,   ~'G2 (df)',    ~CFI,
  'Model_1',  '413.42 (2)',  .95, 
  'Model_2',  '532.93 (3)',  .91, 
)

target_long_df <- tribble(
  ~Statistc,   ~Model_1,    ~Model_2,
  'G2 (df)',   '413.42 (2)',  '532.93 (3)',
  'CFI',      .95,          .91,
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use `str_c` `wide_df %>% unite(`G2 (df)`, G2, df, sep=" (") %>% mutate(`G2 (df)` = str_c(`G2 (df)`, ')'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 'long_df', we can do

```
library(tidyverse)
long_df %>%
    group_by(grp = rep(1:2, 2:1)) %>% 
    summarise_all(list(~ if(n() > 1) str_c(.[1], ' (', .[2], ')') 
          else as.character(.))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

---

From `wide_df`, a similar approach with `str_c` or `str_c` +`unite` can be tried

```
wide_df %>%
     unite(`G2 (df)`, G2, df, sep=" (") %>% 
     mutate(`G2 (df)` = str_c(`G2 (df)`, ')'))
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I wouldn't have thought to create an index in the group_by.

Comment: How does this scale for cases where there are more rows in the long_df? I can see the `summarise_all...dplyr::n()` creates summary counts for grp. However, if I have more rows in the long_df the function doesn't scale, and changing the logical in the `if(n() >1)` to a different value results in error. I'd assume if there were more rows then the grp call could be scaled as 1,1,2,2,2,2, and the logical could be changed to == 2. Thanks.

Comment: @bfoste01  Is there any patterns in the data that suggests which rows to be grouped at

Comment: That clue was helpful. I think I solved it, though not the most elegant way. Instead of creating the grp index in the `group_by`, I created the following: `mutate(grp = c(rep(1,2), seq(nrow(long_df)-(nrow(long_df)-2), length = nrow(long_df)-2)))`. The dynamic portions probably are not needed, since this is the last stage of analytic work, and I could simply go with: 'mutate(2, seq(3, length = 3))'. Not sure, which is better practice. The latter is more readable.

Comment: @bfoste01  Instead of `rep`, you may also create the grouping variable with `gl`

Comment: Thank you. I learned a few things with your responses, which is always the best case.